# precision regarding timestamp of sent text message on iphone

Tags: iphone, text

Is the timestamp of a sent text message on iphone is the timestamp of when the user sent it from his phone (pressed the send button), or the timestamp of when it was acknowledged/received by a cell tower (or something else)?

In other words, can a text message sent earlier in a zone without cell tower coverage end up with a later timestamp, when it is actually picked up by a cell tower. Or is it always the timestamp of when it's sent from the phone, regardless of when it's received by the cell network?